# How to fetch an AirPort/Wi-Fi password using /usr/bin/security

Tags: security, airport, password, unix

I have been trying to use /usr/bin/security rather than hard coding login/password information into scripts. For example, here's how you get the password for 'pinboard.in'

```
security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-internet-password -gs pinboard.in |\
grep '^password: ' |\
sed 's#^password: "##g ; s#"$##'
```

*(Note: Someone who is better at grep/awk can probably combine those last two lines, just be sure to consider for when a password may have a " in it — or a space.)*

What I *can't* do is figure out how to retrieve the password for a Wi-Fi network if all I know is the SSID.

I have even tried specifying the kind of data I am looking for with `-D`:

`security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -s MySSIDhere`

but all I get is this

`security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.`

All I have found via Google has been about *adding* SSID password information on the CLI, but I want to *retrieve* it.

Comment: Are Wi-Fi passwords stored in the keychain? I don’t think so.

Comment: Yes, they are...

Comment: You are not on Mountain Lion I assume, the `sed` doesn't work there anymore (at least not for Skype, different output format). To get rid of the grep use `... | sed '/^password: /s#^...`

Answer (score 4):

I got my password with

```
security find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -a YourSSIDhere -g
```

Main difference is `-a SSID`. I found that in which field it was stored by letting security take a dump:

```
security dump-keychain
```

Comment: That's not working for me.

Comment: @TJLuoma If you could add a little bit more details (what was the output of the command, did you run `security dump-keychain` first, etc.), someone may be able to help you.